# Error 'block_is_haml?' Haml = f.label in Ruby 1.9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

app/views/users/_form.html.haml, line 10

```
= form_for @user do |f|
  - if @user.errors.any?
    #error_explanation
      %h2= "#{pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error")} prohibido que este usuario se guarde:"
      %ul
        - @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
          %li= msg

  .field
    = f.label 'Usuario'
    = f.text_field :username
  .field
    = f.label :email
    = f.text_field :email
  .field
    = f.label 'Teléfono'
    = f.phone_field :phone
  .field
    = f.label 'Contraseña'
    = f.password_field :password
  .field
    = f.label 'Reingresar Contraseña'
    = f.password_field :password_confirmation
  .control-group
    //= f.label 'Permisos'
    %ul.unstyled
      - for role in Role.find(:all)
        %li
          = check_box_tag "user[role_ids][]", role.name, @user.roles.include?(role)
          = role.name
    %br
  .actions
    = f.submit 'Guardar',:class => 'btn btn-primary'
```

Error seems to be in the `= f.label` I've deleted all the `= f.label` and no errors were thrown, also changed `= f.label 'Usuario'` for `= f.label :username` with no luck.

Error Message:

```
ArgumentError in Users#new

Showing C:/Sites/AutosCostaRica/app/views/users/_form.html.haml where line #10 raised:

syntax error in "<reader>", line 3, column 18:
        next_label: >>
                     ^
```

Update:

I just found out that it works perfect on Ruby 1.8, but I waned to be 1.9.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you want an answer it would be extremely helpful if you posted the error (copy/paste) as it appears in your log/browser. We're not mind readers. :)

Comment: Does it have the same error if you take out that blank line? I vaguely recall having a problem with a blank line without indentation at one point, but could be mis-remembering.

Comment: Same problem :( not working without the blank line.